# Recompiling jar files

Tags: java, android-studio, jar

In trying to add jar files to my AndroidStudio project. I get a very long error.  My reasons for adding the jar files are to get access to certain classes.  For instance the ability to SFTP, and taking a PCM file and changing the sampling rate from 44100 to 16000.  So the jars are so I can import the following:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.*;
com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
```

However at build time the key points of this error I get are

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
        (com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$1) that doesn't come with an
        associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
        compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
        solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
        and without specifying any "-target" type options.
```

I have tried finding different versions of the jar files, or downloading the source to recompile via command line.

How do I build a project that will compile a library I can use in my own app?

How do I compile the source from the jars, or where can I find the right type of jars (if that's the case).

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially grab the sources from http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ and compile the jar files yourself. However, I would first check if you have the most recent version available - that might solve your problem as well.